# REST API for updating 10k Records at once

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

I have a business requirement to update 10,000 - 15,000 records at once every Monday. I am using the REST API to update Accounts. My question is if I can call the API using Batches instead of calling the API to update each record one at a time.

What is the suggested approach for handling this type of situation? What endpoint would I have to hit? What would the body of the request need to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explore Bulk API. It has capabilities to load/process large chunks.

You can see the limitations here - [Bulk API Allocation Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_bulkapi.htm#:%7E:text=Batches%20for%20data%20loads%20can,a%20maximum%20of%2032%2C000%20characters.)

For more details on how to use, you can see Trailhead link - [Trailhead Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_bulk)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sObject update collections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_update.htm) to deal with up to 200 records at once.

It uses:

```
PATCH /vXX.X/composite/sobjects
```

This is the same basic feature as the SOAP equivalent. If you want to deal with many thousands of records with just a few API calls, the Bulk API may be right for you (see [other answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/311997)). However, for most use cases, this API is perfectly adequate in terms of performance and minimal API usage.

Comment: that number might be as low as 25